# how to fix datatables not show data

Tags: jquery, datatables

jquery-1.7.1,
datatables-1.8.2

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#Table1').dataTable({
            "aaData": [{"id":1,"text":"a"},{"id":2,"text":"b"},{"id":3,"text":"c"},],
            "aoColumns": [{"mData": "id","sTitle":"id"},{"mData": "text","sTitle":"text"}],
        });
    });
</script>
```

html

```
<table id="Table1"></table>
```

data show null row

how to fix
note ..
i use datatable-1.9.4 is working 
i want use datatables-1.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For datatables 1.8.2, you'll need to use `mDataProp` instead of `mData`. From the documentation: "Note that prior to DataTables 1.9.2 mData was called mDataProp." http://datatables.net/ref

You also have some extra commas at the end of `aaData` and `aoColumns`; Internet Explorer will not like that and will error out before rendering your table.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfGmj/)**